# jquery to set dotnet form visible=true and false

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a tabbed login page, that I would like to host a single form on each tab, but from the code behind they are on a single page.

This means there are two forms.

example:

```
<nav id="secondary">
<ul>
<li id="current"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#forgot">Forgot Password</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>


<div id="login" class="tab">
<br /><br />
<form runat="server" visible="true" class="frmControl">
</form>
</div>
<div id="forgot" class="tab">
<br /><br />
<form runat="server" visible="false" class="frmControl"></form>
</div>
```

and then I have the following jquery to toggle between the login div and forgot div

```
$(".tab").hide();

if ($("nav#secondary ul li.current").length < 1) {
    $("nav#secondary ul li:first-child").addClass("current");
}

var link = $("nav#secondary ul li.current a").attr("href");
$(link).show();

$("nav#secondary ul li a").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
        $("nav#secondary ul li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(".tab").hide();
        $(".frmControl").attr("Visible", "false");
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        $(this).attr("Visible", "true");
        $(link).show();
        initBackground();
    }
    return false;
});
```

It is not working correctly, as it is only setting the '.frmControl' class to visible=false. but when i reactivate the tab, it does not set this to true again for the active tab form and set the inactive tab form to false.

sorry if I am not explaining this correctly.

-RD

Comment: You can't have more than one form be `runat="server"` and a form doesn't have a client-side `Visible` property, at least one that will do you any good.  You need to use `hide/show`.

Answer (score 0):

you do not want to set   `$(".frmControl").attr("Visible", "false");` because you already hiding the tab using `$(".tab").hide();`

```
$(".tab").hide();

if ($("nav#secondary ul li.current").length < 1) {
    $("nav#secondary ul li:first-child").addClass("current");
}

var link = $("nav#secondary ul li.current a").attr("href");
$(link).show();

$("nav#secondary ul li a").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
        $("nav#secondary ul li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(".tab").hide();
      //  $(".frmControl").attr("Visible", "false");// remove this line
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        $(this).attr("Visible", "true");
        $(link).show();
        initBackground();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/VGRZS/

Comment: this did not work, because when i click on login, the login div including the form should be visible -- but the forget div and form should not be visible and vice versa is true for forget.

what i just realized is that the form controls are runat server, which means i'll need to change the switch to also trigger the visible=true / visible = false on server side.

i'll report back after i try some thoughts out.

thanks!